# How to change Max Schedulable Application for Hadoop Apache 2.2

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am playing around with capacity-scheduler. I have updated number of total applications running on cluster and total number of applications that can be submitted by user more than 1 respectively. Yet it does not allow me to submit more than one job. I was going through the scheduler configuration available at Web Interface, and I came across Max Schedulable Applications, of whose value is 1.

Can some one please tell me which property do I need to add to get maximum schedulable applications more than 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've patched `/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
  <value>100</value>
  <description>
    Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run
    application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
    applications.
  </description>
</property>
```

And that increased `Max Schedulable Applications` property.

EDIT: In newer versions of Hadoop Yarn the value for yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent is [given as a float](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) where 0.5 = 50% and 1.0 = 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the memory for Application Master and I allowed me to schedule multiple jobs on cluster.